# Combine two query and display in single line

Tags: sql-server

I am using the below code to find the sales by credit card and cash and the current output show as below but I want to get the card and cash sales in single line.

current output:

[image: Current Output]

expected output:

[image: Expected Output]

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreateDate, 103) DT,SUM(AMOUNT),NULL FROM JnlDetails WHERE  JnlDetails.CreateDate > '2021-05-01' 
AND ACCOUNTID = '000153200101'
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreateDate, 103)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreateDate, 103) DT,NULL,SUM(AMOUNT) FROM JnlDetails WHERE  JnlDetails.CreateDate > '2021-05-01' 
AND ACCOUNTID = '000153200201'
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreateDate, 103)
ORDER BY DT
```

Is there any other option available to achieve this without Union? Both the information's (Card and Sales) in the same table, based on the accountid we can split.

Comment: You can use a `case expression`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain in detail if possible?

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: By the way, to strip out time from `datetime` just convert to `date`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the `AccountId` value is what differentiates - note they are different for each unioned query.

Comment: @Stu thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `case expression` you can `conditionally sum` your values

```
select Convert(varchar(10), CreateDate, 103) DT,
    Sum (case when ACCOUNTID = '000153200101' then AMOUNT end) as Cash,
    Sum (case when ACCOUNTID = '000153200201' then AMOUNT end) as Card
from JnlDetails
where JnlDetails.CreateDate > '2021-05-01' 
    and ACCOUNTID in ('000153200101','000153200201')
group by Convert(varchar(10), CreateDate, 103)
```

Comment: When I try the above code it is showing the bellow error
 ```Column 'JnlDetails.CreateDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause```

Comment: That part is unchanged from your query - are you sure you have included the `group by`

Comment: I am sorry, It is my mistake.. It is working perfect. Thank you very much for your great help.

Comment: I am new to this stackflow and I would like to mark this answer as best answer like other forums. Is any option?